# Retrieving and displaying image that was uploaded via multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

I'm uploading an image to ./public/images via multer... It is uploading just fine and I can see it in the folder as well as in the DB properly associated and all..

Here is the post route:

```
exports.postRevive = (req, res, next) => {
  var reviveShowName = req.body.reviveShowName;
  var reviveGoal = req.body.reviveGoal;
  var reviveTitle = req.body.reviveTitle;
  var reviveVideo = req.body.reviveVideo;
  var reviveStory = req.body.reviveStory;
  var reviveCategory = req.body.reviveCategory;
  var revivePhoto = req.file.filename;
  var author = {
    id: req.user._id,
    username: req.user.name
  };

  var newRevive = {reviveShowName: reviveShowName, reviveGoal: reviveGoal, reviveTitle: reviveTitle, revivePhoto: revivePhoto, reviveVideo: reviveVideo, reviveStory: reviveStory, author: author, reviveCategory: reviveCategory};
  Revive.create(newRevive, function(err, newlyCreatedRevive) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
};
```

Then I query the db and pass everything to home.pug and in home.pug I'm trying to display it:

Here is the code for home.pug:

```
if revives
  each revive, i in revives 
    .clearfix
      a.slide.revive(href='#')
        .media
          img(src='/images/#{revive.revivePhoto}')
          .funding
            h2 $12,151 of #{revive.reviveGoal}
            .funds
              .fund-bar
                .progress-bar(style='width:82%')
        span.favorite
        .copy
          p.secondary 8.7/10 • Animation, Comedy
          h3.ellipsis
            h4=revive.reviveTitle
```

**=revive.reviveTitle shows up, #{revive.reviveGoal} shows up... The image does not and I can not figure out why...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the only mistake is in the .pug syntax. I was using the .jade syntax but .pug is slightly different

instead of `img(src='/images/#{revive.revivePhoto}')`

it should be `img(src='/images/'+revive.revivePhoto)`

One of the few subtle changes in pug/jade...